# Azure devops terraform pipeline generate client id and secret

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, az

I am using this terraform manifest to deploy AKS on Azure. I can do this via the commandline fine and it works, as I have azure cli configured on my machine to generate client id and secret

[https://github.com/anubhavmishra/terraform-azurerm-aks](http://%20https://github.com/anubhavmishra/terraform-azurerm-aks)

However, I am now building this on Azure Devops Pipeline

So, far i have managed to run terraform init and plan with backend storage on Azure, using Azure Devops using this extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform

Question: How do i get client id and secret on the Azure devops pipeline and set that as an environment variable for terraform? I tried creating a bash az command in the pipeline

```
> az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor"
> --scopes="/subscriptions/YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
```

but failed with this error

```
> 2019-03-27T10:41:58.1042923Z 
2019-03-27T10:41:58.1055624Z Setting AZURE_CONFIG_DIR env variable to: /home/vsts/work/_temp/.azclitask
2019-03-27T10:41:58.1060006Z Setting active cloud to: AzureCloud
2019-03-27T10:41:58.1069887Z [command]/usr/bin/az cloud set -n AzureCloud
2019-03-27T10:41:58.9004429Z [command]/usr/bin/az login --service-principal -u *** -p *** --tenant ***
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0695154Z [
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0696915Z   {
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0697522Z     "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0698958Z     "id": "88bfee03-551c-4ed3-98b0-be68aee330bb",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0704752Z     "isDefault": true,
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0705381Z     "name": "Visual Studio Enterprise",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0706362Z     "state": "Enabled",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0707434Z     "tenantId": "***",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0716107Z     "user": {
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0717485Z       "name": "***",
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0718161Z       "type": "servicePrincipal"
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0718675Z     }
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0719185Z   }
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0719831Z ]
2019-03-27T10:42:00.0728173Z [command]/usr/bin/az account set --subscription 88bfee03-551c-4ed3-98b0-be68aee330bb
2019-03-27T10:42:00.8569816Z [command]/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1553683312219.sh
2019-03-27T10:42:02.4431342Z ERROR: Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. For how to configure, please refer 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal'. Original error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
2019-03-27T10:42:02.5271752Z [command]/usr/bin/az account clear
2019-03-27T10:42:03.3092558Z ##[error]Script failed with error: Error: /bin/bash failed with return code: 1
2019-03-27T10:42:03.3108490Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure CLI
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it with Azure Pipelines.

1. Create a Service Principal for Terraform.
2. Create the following variables in your pipeline

   - ARM_CLIENT_ID
   - ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
   - ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
   - ARM_TENANT_ID

If you choose to store ARM_CLIENT_SECRET as a secret in Azure DevOps you will need to do the following in your task under the *Environment Variables* sections of the task to get it decrypted so terraform can read it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to grant your service connections rights to create service principals. but I'd generally advise against that, just precreate a service principal and use it in your pipeline. creating a new service principal on each run seems excessive.

you can use build\release variables and populate those with client id\secret

Comment: so i create service principal on Azure and then attach to the pipeline, do i need to populate the client id and secret everytime i need to run the pipeline?

Comment: no, just put them into build\release variables and reference those in your script. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Comment: is there a security risk?

Comment: probably less than generating new service principal every run

Comment: i have added the variables on the release pipeline, however they are not available to the terraform plan task, so i need to do anything else, basically i want them as bash environment variable when terraform is run

Comment: they are, i think if you marked them as secure, you need to redefine them, if they are not secure they are just available

Comment: redefine where? i set variable to type secret on PIplines -> release -> varibles section

Comment: eg. terraform, var.client_id reads from $ARM_CLIENT_ID in bash, will it be the same in pipeline?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

Comment: i am not using the yaml file, instead terraform cli extension on the release pipeline

Comment: it doesnt matter, you just need to pull those values in the task and assign to environment variable

Comment: ok the variables are loaded, however they are loaded as SECRET_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID instead of ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID , anyway to load that without the SECRET ??? Azure terraform module does not recognize that environment variable....

Comment: if they are secret - no, you have to redefine them

Answer (score 0):

The approach defined in the post https://medium.com/@maninder.bindra/creating-a-single-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-to-provision-multiple-environments-using-terraform-e6d05343cae2?
  can be considered as well. Here the Keyvault task is used to fetch the secrets from Azure Vault (these include terraform backend access secrets as well as aks sp secrets):

```
#KEY VAULT TASK
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(environment)-sp'
    KeyVaultName: '$(environment)-pipeline-secrets-kv'
    SecretsFilter: 'tf-sp-id,tf-sp-secret,tf-tenant-id,tf-subscription-id,tf-backend-sa-access-key,aks-sp-id,aks-sp-secret'
  displayName: 'Get key vault secrets as pipeline variables'
```

And then you can use the secrets as variables in the rest of the pipeline. FOr instance aks-sp-id can be referred to as $(aks-sp-id). So the bash/azure-cli task can be something like

```
# AZ LOGIN USING TERRAFORM SERVICE PRINCIPAL
- script: |
    az login --service-principal -u $(tf-sp-id) -p $(tf-sp-secret) --tenant $(tf-tenant-id)
    cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/tf-infra-provision
```

Followed by terraform init and plan (plan shown below, see post for complete pipeline details)

```
# TERRAFORM PLAN    
    echo '#######Terraform Plan########'
    terraform plan -var-file=./tf-vars/$(tfvarsFile) -var="client_id=$(tf-sp-id)" -var="client_secret=$(tf-sp-secret)" -var="tenant_id=$(tf-tenant-id)" -var="subscription_id=$(tf-subscription-id)" -var="aks_sp_id=$(aks-sp-id)" -var="aks_sp_secret=$(aks-sp-secret)" -out="out.plan"
```

Hope this helps.